# Laravel Query with Multiple Tables Join and Multiple Join Fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a query to join multiple tables with multiple join fields.

This is the code:

```
        $crew = DB::table('crew')
            ->join('aclist', function ($join){
                $join->on(function($query){
                  $query->on('aclist.ac_config', '=', 'crew.config')
                        ->on('aclist.ac_type', '=', 'crew.ac_type');
                });
            })
            // Error happened after I add this indexform join script
            ->join('indexform', function ($join){
                $join->on(function($query){
                $query->on('indexform.config', '=', 'crew.config')
                       ->on('indexform.ac_type', '=', 'crew.ac_type');
                });
            })        

            ->select('crew.*','indexform.*')
            ->where('aclist.ac_reg', $input['acreg'])
            ->get();
```

Below is the view code, and it's no longer working after I add the indexform join script

```
     @foreach ($crew as $crw)
        <tr>
        <td class="container" align="center" colspan="4">{{$crw->description}}</td>
        <td class="container" align="center">{{$crw->qty}}</td>
        <td class="container" align="center">{{$crw->arm_meter}}</td>
        <td class="container" align="center">{{$crw->weight_kg}}</td>
        <td class="container" align="center">{{$crw->index}}</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
```

The query work well before I add the script to join the indexform tables.
Please help how to build query to join three tables with multiple "on" criteria.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The view code is no longer returning values after I add the indexform join script

Comment: Looks like there is no data that can satisfy all constraints. Does `crew` contain entries that have matching entries in `aclist` AND `indexform`?